# what is the safe way to do redirect 301 to 404 error to prevent errors in google webmaster?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

how to do it through the nginx (wordpress) 301 redirect of the page with error 404 to homepage safely?:

```
# define error page
    error_page 404 = @notfound;

    # error page location redirect 301
    location @notfound {
        return 301 /;
    }
```

( an addendum, this 301 redirect in the nginx block does not work on a specific theme, where could be the barrier? )
no **404.php** de um theme, of a theme, I'm using this:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
exit();
?>
```

It works fine, it redirects yes, **but by this method(php!!), is it really doing with 301?** **to safely prevent 404 errors in google webmaster?** It's good SEO practice?

**I know by nginx, this is correct, but I would like to know in php, if this really has 301 real effect!**

Thanks all.

Comment: Isn't that bad to not even know what urls are giving 404?

Comment: Is not that bad to not even know what urls are giving 404?
I always know, in most cases everybody knows, 404 is page is found, this error happens when you delete old posts, and my posts are published for a maximum of 5 months, I delete the old ones, and I make thousands of errors in the google, do you have any idea if this php mode is the same as the nginx mode that I posted in the question?

Comment: Yes, they both look equivalent. But only if you also add `proxy_intercept_errors on;` to your `proxy_pass` block. See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors for more details

Comment: Thanks for comment. I'm using this:
# intercept errors for 404 redirect
**fastcgi_intercept_errors on;**
(inside the block ``location ~ \ .php$`` - I am ``fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;``)
this has some relation with:
**proxy_intercept_errors on**

Comment: So what is the issue now? Do `curl -v http://yoursite.com/ainvailiduri/` and see if you are get 301 or not

Comment: I posted the result here ( https://pastebin.com/NTG6vci9 ) and made comments. Thanks.

Comment: As you can it is a 301, so this is correct

Comment: Thanks. I'm much calmer now.